# How do I get my redirect to run successfully when a user selects choice between two radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot get my redirect to successfully work on the users choice selected between two radio buttons.

I have tried both the window.location.href and the window.location.replace to try get me redirect to work. All files are saved the same folder as the current file but neither option is successfully redirecting onsubmit of the form after a users chooses between two options given in the radio buttton the is supposed to link to one of two simple math functions. Note that the function also includes a cookie that remembers the users radio button selection.

```js
//* calling math function according to checked radio button.
//* creating cookie to remember users choice finish

window.onload = function() {
  if (document.cookie.length != 0) {
    var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("="); //*splits cookie at = 
    to
    return correct boolen value 'true'
    document.button = nameValueArray[1]; //* creates array between button 
    choices
    getElementById("converter").value = nameValueArray[1];
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var buttonChoiceGrams = document.getElementById("grams").checked;
  var buttonChoiceOunces = document.getElementById("ounces").checked;

  if ((buttonChoiceGrams == false) && (buttonChoiceOunces == false)) {
    var msg = alert('You must select your weight conversion choice!');
  } else if (buttonChoiceGrams == true) {
    alert(buttonChoiceGrams);
    document.buttonChoiceGrams = buttonChoiceGrams;
    document.cookie = "buttonGrams" + true + ";expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2020 
    01: 00: 00 UCT;
    ";
    window.location.replace = "grams_to_ounces.html"; //* redirect to math 
    function selected in radio button
  } else if (buttonChoiceOunces == true) {
    alert(buttonChoiceOunces);
    document.buttonChoiceOunces = buttonChoiceOunces;
    document.cookie = "buttonOunces" + true + ";expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2020 
    01: 00: 00 UCT;
    ";
    window.location.replace = "ounces_to_grams.html"; //* redirect to math 
    function selected in radio button
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Weight converter selection</title>
</head>
<!--radio button weight convertion choices-->

<body>
  <form action="" method="POST" id="converter" onsubmit="myFunction()">
    <label><strong>Weight conversions:</strong></label>
    <br /> <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="converter" value="grams" id="grams" />Grams to Ounces
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="converter" value="ounces" id="ounces" />Ounces to Grams
    <br /> <br/>
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Okay" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full file path and `window.location.href`

```
window.location.href="file://host/path/grams_to_ounces.html"
```

In my example above you will need to replace the `host/path/` with your own file structure.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is what happens in your situation:

1. User submits form
2. `myFunction()` is executed
3. The browser continues processing submission and thus goes to URL defined in `<form action="...">`

#### How to fix it?

`return false;` at the end of `myFunction()`. This will interrupt further processing of form submission. Redirects with `window.location` will start having an effect.